# Error [Cookie file not found, creating cookie...] with InstaPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, instagram, instapy

I am starting to use the InstaPy library. To do this I launched the `quickstart.py` file to test the bot. I entered a username and password of a valid instagram account but my bot is still stuck on the cookies page.

During the execution (in headless_browser=False), the browser loads the instagram page but remains blocked. Here is the error message I get:

```
No any custom workspace provided.   ~using existing..
InstaPy Version: 0.6.16
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "/home/clement-gaudiniere/InstaPy"
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
INFO [2022-10-26 15:12:06] [potat_oloh]  Session started!
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
INFO [2022-10-26 15:12:11] [potat_oloh]  - Cookie file not found, creating cookie...
WARNING [2022-10-26 15:12:22] [potat_oloh]  Login A/B test detected! Trying another string...
WARNING [2022-10-26 15:12:27] [potat_oloh]  Could not pass the login A/B test. 
Trying last string...
ERROR [2022-10-26 15:12:32] [potat_oloh]  Login A/B test failed!
b"Message: Unable to locate element: //div[text()='Log In']\nStacktrace:\nRemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1\nWebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5\nNoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5\nelement.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16\n"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/InstaPy/instapy/login_util.py", line 337, in login_user
login_elem = browser.find_element(
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //button[text()='Log In']
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/InstaPy/instapy/login_util.py", line 343, in login_user
login_elem = browser.find_element(
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[text()='Log in']
6Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/InstaPy/instapy/login_util.py", line 350, in login_user
login_elem = browser.find_element(
 File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
 File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "/home/clement-gaudiniere/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[text()='Log In']
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16

........................................................................................................................
CRITICAL [2022-10-26 15:12:32] [potat_oloh]  Unable to login to Instagram! You will find more information in the logs above.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



INFO [2022-10-26 15:12:32] [potat_oloh]  Sessional Live Report:
|> No any statistics to show


[Session lasted 30.31 seconds]
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
INFO [2022-10-26 15:12:32] [potat_oloh]  Session ended!
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

I tried several proposed solutions but nothing worked, I always get another error message, would you have an idea?